# Is evil Missy ("Big Mouth") a reference to "Us" (2019)?

Tags: reference, get-out, us, big-mouth

In Season 2, Episode 2 of *Big Mouth* ("What Is It About Boobs?"), an evil version of Missy comes out of the mirror:

[image: character facing evil reflection]

Is this a reference to the movie *Us* (2019)? Later in this *Big Mouth* season there is a more explicit reference to the movie *Get Out*. Both *Us* and *Get Out* were written and directed by Jordan Peele, who voices a few characters in *Big Mouth*.

The only thing keeping me from being sure that evil Missy is a clear reference to *Us* is that this season of *Big Mouth* was released in October 2018, while *Us* would only be released in March 2019. Since both *Us* and season 2 of *Big Mouth* were (likely?) in production during most of 2018, could this is an easter egg Peele managed to slip in?

Comment: That's hardly a new idea https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MirrorUniverse